# Are BLE-enabled devices discoverable by default?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking to do something similar to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94490/counting-number-of-bluetooth-4-0-ble-devices-near-me), based on the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/94522/95643) it suggests that devices are only discoverable if they are emitting packets of information.

What I would like to understand is, do devices like mobile phones (iOS/Android) send these discoverable packets by default? Or would they need to be configured (e.g. via an app) to explicitly advertise themselves or some bits of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not discoverable by default.

Vol 3 of the [Bluetooth 4.x spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439&_ga=1.163940223.192467529.1451461984) defines two discoverable modes:

- 9.2.3 - Limited Discoverable Mode

> The limited discoverable mode is typically used when a
>   user performs a specific action to make the device discoverable for a limited
>   period of time.

- 9.2.4 - General Discoverable Mode

> The
>   general discoverable mode is typically used when the device is intending to be
>   discoverable for a long period of time.

A good BLE design will be to have the device dormant indefinitely to conserve battery power until some action is required. It is entirely up to the designer to decide when to advertise, for how long, and at what interval. You can have it button activated or active immediately from boot.

However, if your device has no user interface and no way of being manually activated (such as a broadcasting sensor node) then it would seem that you have no choice but to use General Discoverable Mode, and advertise continuously. You will have to choose an advertising interval which is the best compromise between conserving power and being discoverable.

It is also possible to have recurring windows of Limited Discoverable Mode.

The Laird module I'm using has this in an [app note](http://www.lairdtech.com/brandworld/library/Application%20Note%20-%20smartBASIC%20for%20Bluetooth%20Low%20Energy%20Modules.pdf):

> Because BLE is designed to save power, the device is typically dormant until action is required.

I have also found [this quote](http://www.argenox.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-v4-0-development/library/a-ble-advertising-primer/):

> A large number of BLE products sleep most of the time, waking up only to advertise and connect when needed. This means advertisements have a big impact on power consumption.

And to answer the 2nd part of your question, [If a device isn't advertising, it's impossible for any Central to connect to it.](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/4991/nrf51822-how-to-set-device-to-non-discovery-mode/?answer=7170#post-id-7170)

Now, with all that said. A lot of devices *do advertise all the time* from the moment the batteries are installed. As an example, devices compatible with Apple iBeacon will advertise continuously at 100ms interval until the batteries die. An interesting introduction to the topic of advertising interval vs battery life [is given here](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201567802-Advertising-Interval).

Comment: Isn't BLE always on though? I thought the whole point was it, by implementation, uses very little battery power.

Comment: Well @James, You have certainly got me thinking. I'm currently upgrading a product from classic BT to BLE and I am planning to have a button-activated 1-minute pairing-window after which the BLE module goes totally dormant (unless a connection has been made). I concede that the Laird module I've been looking at does such a good job of encapsulating the BLE specific implementation that I've not had to learn much about it in order to get it working.

Comment: added some extra quick research, hopefully it is is useful. please feel free to share any info you find, I feel I still have a lot to learn on BLE.

Comment: +1 thanks for the info, very useful. However, I'm not actually interested in connecting to devices at all, I just want to know if they are within the vicinity. If said devices where to be broadcasting packets of information that included their MAC address that would be enough, doesn't sound like that's the "norm" for BLE though. I guess what I was hoping for was if I had a device that was actively scanning, the peripheral devices would emit a "I can see you" type response, seems like peripherals won't do this unless they are explicitly told to do so on reading X data.

Comment: I just dont think its that easy to generalise. The scope of bt 4.x covers such a vast spread of different devices, all with different behaviours and allowing many proprietary customisations.

Comment: yeah, I was hoping there was perhaps a default handshake scenario all devices had to go through i.e. beacon: "I'm here", device: "I see you" - anything beyond this like connecting / exchanging data would be an device-dependant implementation.

Comment: well, you are not totally wrong... only that "BLE-enabled devices" is too broad as a category. If you pick a subset of devices, e.g. devices supporting Apple iBeacon, then yes, they will all be squitting advertisements continuously from the moment the batteries are installed, at 100ms interval. In fact, now knowing what your goal is... in fact *a lot* of devices *do* advertise all the time... just not all!!  I've added a final paragraph to the answer. I think I'm going to leave it there. Thanks for the interesting discussion.

Comment: I know ultimately there will be limitations, however, most modern phones (which most likely take up the majority of the market share these days) should have beacon support. It's never going to be 100% accurate but if it can get you in the ballpark it would be good enough :) thanks for your time & effort!

Answer (score 4):

This strongly depends on the nature of the device.

#### Mobile phones, Tables

First of all not all mobile phones can advertise at all.  Newer ones can.  For example, Android 5.0 got the ability to advertise.  Earlier versions could be only central or observer.
Those that can advertise don't advertise by default.  Advertising has to be enabled from an app.

#### Beacons

Beacons, on the other hand advertise by default.  They advertise all the time.  Broadcasting advertisement is all they do.

Comment: I am strictly referring to BT 4.0 enabled devices here, unless you mean some are restricted by OS? Is there a diff between being discoverable vs advertising? For example, do BLE devices (given its "always enabled") search for nearby beacons? (similar to Wifi)

Comment: First, you were asking "do devices [...] **send** these discoverable packets by default?"  Now you are asking "do BLE devices [...] **search** for nearby beacons?"  So which is it?  It's unclear to me what you want.

Comment: the question is still the same, ultimately if a device is searching it's *sending* a packet. I'm just interested in knowing whether a BLE enabled device would send packets without being explicitly configured to do so (e.g. like a "I am here" type packet)

Comment: @James - When a Bluetooth LE device is "searching" it is merely listening for advertising packets. It's not broadcasting any itself. Even the beacons and other devices that Nick mentions above need to be programmed (firmware, etc.) to send advertisement packets. For things like iBeacons, the only thing they do is advertise, but others allow connections and will generally stop advertising once a connection has been established.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks, yeah everything I've read so far alludes to this - I don't know the inner workings of the BLE stack therefore I wasn't sure if they did broadcast a general "I'm here" type packet (in hindsight though, that's effectively what advertising is).

Comment: @BradLarson I presume when a peripheral "sees" advertising data, it doesn't automatically try to communicate with it? For example, a handshake type scenario that happens between the 2 devices i.e. beacon: "I'm here", device: "I see you!"?

Comment: @James - What a device does in response to advertising data is entirely up to its programming / design. For things like iBeacons, there's no reason to connect to them, so the receiving device merely takes in the advertisements and extracts data from them. No response is sent, nor would the iBeacon do anything with it if one was sent. For devices that use connections, a connection can be initiated in response to an advertising packet, but it doesn't have to be. It all depends on what the central device wants to do.