# BLE Gateway not reading smartphones BLE signals

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using a Minew G1 Gateway to collect both beacons and BLE devices.
Doing some test, I see that it detects beacons and various devices (smart TVs, smartwatches) but I can't find any of smartphones nearby. I find several unknown devices, but their mac address doesn't correspond with those of my phones.
Smartphones used are at least 4.2 bluetooth version.

Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Smartphones don't advertise BLE packets all the time. Only when an app or the user starts advertising.

Answer (score 0):

As Emil said, you need an app to enable BLE adverts on smartphones to make them discoverable to scanning devices. Have a look at the links below:-

- [BLE is working between two mobile phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526641/bluetooth-low-energy-is-working-between-two-mobile-phone)
- [Are BLE enabled devices discoverable by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519357/are-ble-enabled-devices-discoverable-by-default)